# Can "el &&" be omitted from the for condition?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, dom, parent

```
function parents(element, selector) {
  for (let el = element; el && el !== document; el = el.parentNode) {
    if (el.matches(selector)) {
      return el;
    }
  }
  return null;
}
parents(anyChild, '#inexistent');
```

Is there a real-life situation where `el &&` will be required or I can leave just the `el !== document` part?

I can't think of any, except if I don't pass an element or I pass an invalid one.

Comment: No it cannot. To see why, look at that last part of the `for(...; ...; ...)`. What happens to `el`?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans - I think the OP's logic is that the `parentNode` of the `html` element (the `documentElement`) is `document`.

Comment: Right, which is why we agree that you can't get rid of `el &&`?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans - I think we get there differently, but yes, we agree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If something calls `parents` with a valid element that isn't in the DOM, you need that condition to prevent an error.

Consider:

```
const div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = "<span><span class='foo'></span></span>";
const span = div.querySelector(".foo");
// ...
const blah = parents(span, ".blah");
```

`parentNode` will reach `null` without ever first being `=== document`. Similarly:

```
const div = document.getElementById(".something");
div.remove(); // Or on older browsers: div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
const blah = parents(div, ".blah");
```

---

Side note: What you have there is effectively the [`closest`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-element-closest) method. You might consider just using that instead, with a good polyfill if you have to support obsolete browsers.

Comment: Should I worry about that if I will be the only one using that function (within a personal project)?

Comment: @user557108 - That's up to you. Years ago browsers were a bit inconsistent with what happened above the document element. In any project I was working with, I'd have the guard there (and stop at `document.documentElement` rather than `document`). Or better yet, I'd use [`closest`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-element-closest) with a good polyfill if necessary. ;-)